Trying to figure out serial communication checksum
I want to be able to communicate with and setup one of my appliances (a Franke Pura coffee machine) with an ESP32. Communication via RS232 works fine. I am able to sniff the protocol when a computer is connected with original software. But to set it up I have to generate a checksum. Some examples on communication:
0x00 0x02 0x01 0x03 0x5F 0x14 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x07 0x03 0xE8 0x34 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x03 0x03 0xA4 0x6F 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x05 0x03 0x13 0x4F 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x2F 0x03 0xDD 0xAD 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x2B 0x03 0x91 0xF6 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x3D 0x03 0xAD 0x17 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x39 0x03 0xE1 0x4C 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x41 0x03 0xBF 0xE7 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x55 0x03 0x78 0x7D 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x51 0x03 0x34 0x26 0x00

I guess first and last byte is start and end signal and skip those(?) Here there are a 3 byte command and a 2 byte checksum.
I have tried some common checksums/crc without luck.
Any checksum gurus out there that can provide some help?
Edit:
Another example with longer message
0x00 0x04 0x3E 0x01 0x01 0x03 0x45 0x27 0x00

Another edit: Add more examples casuse I now realise they are needed but we are getting there it seems thanks to Mark Adler.
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x01 0x03 0x98 0x91 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x01 0x03 0x37 0x93 0x00 
0x00 0x04 0x42 0x01 0x02 0x15 0x70 0x75 0x72 0x61 0x5F 0x6C 0x61 0x6E 0x67 0x5F 0x2A 0x5F 0x75 0x73 0x65 0x72 0x2E 0x73 0x69 0x64 0x03 0xAA 0xD7 0x00 
0x00 0x19 0x3C 0x01 0x70 0x75 0x72 0x61 0x5F 0x6C 0x61 0x6E 0x67 0x5F 0x6E 0x6F 0x72 0x5F 0x75 0x73 0x65 0x72 0x2E 0x73 0x69 0x64 0x03 0x62 0xC0 0x00 

Update: some more messages
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x05 0xA8 0x7D 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x04 0x06 0x72 0x25 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x06 0xDD 0x27 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x04 0x07 0xC8 0x88 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x07 0x67 0x8A 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x04 0x08 0xD2 0x17 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x08 0x7D 0x15 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x04 0x09 0x68 0xBA 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x09 0xC7 0xB8 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x04 0x0A 0x1D 0xE0 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x0A 0xB2 0xE2 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x04 0x0B 0xA7 0x4D 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x0B 0x08 0x4F 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x49 0x04 0x0C 0xF7 0x54 0x00 
0x00 0x02 0x4D 0x04 0x0C 0x58 0x56 0x00 


The last two bytes before the framing zero are a 16-bit CRC (not a checksum). A definition that works is:
width=16  poly=0xbaad  init=0xa130  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0x03bd  residue=0x0000  name=(none)

I say "a" definition since there are many combinations of init and xorout that will give the same CRC value, due to the fact that all of the messages are the same length. As an example, init=0 and xorout=0xd189 works as well. If you had just one message of a different length, then init and xorout could be solved for separately.
The CRC is placed in the message in big-endian order.
Update:
And, indeed, with the now added seven-byte message, those two parameters can be solved for. They are init=0x6454 and xorout=0xc7e0.

Great! That worked fine on the examples I gave but you mentioned diffrent message and I have many.. Tried one but that didnt work. Could you have a look? Thanks!
0x00 0x04 0x3E 0x01 0x01 0x03 0x45 0x27 0x00

Edit your question to include that example.

Did you use some utility to get those values or are they obvious to one skilled in the art?

I use reveng and code that I have written.

Hi Mark! Your new values works for every example I have provided you, but I edited in 4 more examples in the first post. Cause messages with different size dont work for some reason..

The last two long messages cannot be reconciled. You should verify that you transcribed them correctly.

Ok . maybe there is something other going on with the two long ones. I'll look into those..
What do you think about the two above the long ones?
I also added 15 more that does not match when using poly=0xbaad, init=0x6454 and xorout=0xc7e0

Not able to reconcile all those.

Turns out that the data is COBS encoded before it is sent. It is also used a properitary CRC algorithm involving a custom lookup table.
